# Unexpected revert during selfdestruct

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

I experience unexpected revert in the line where I invoke `bidEnd`.

```
  it("should create second contract and remove it", function(done) {
    BiddingsFactory.deployed().then(async function (biddings_factory) {
      await biddings_factory.create("Second", "Second bidding", 2, 20, {from: accounts[2]});
      var biddings = await biddings_factory.getAllBiddings();
      assert.equal(biddings.length, 2, "There are two biddings.");
      var biddingAddress = await biddings_factory.getLastBidding.call();
      var bidding = await Bidding.at(biddingAddress);
      setTimeout(async function () {
        await biddings_factory.remove(biddings.length - 1);
        await bidding.bidEnd({from: accounts[2]});
        var biddingsNumber = await biddings_factory.getNumberOfBiddings.call();
        assert.equal(biddingsNumber, 1, "There is only one bidding.");
        done();
      }, 1000 * 2);
    });
```

Sometimes my test passes but when I rerun, it always fails. The `bidEnd` function body:

```
selfdestruct(owner);
```

It contains modifiers but I remove them for the testing to be clear. What might be the reason?

Comment: I uploded project with the file to GitHub: https://github.com/pw94/BiddingApplication/blob/master/test/biddings_factory.js